# How to reprogram a cheap GPS tracker?

Tags: gps

I was wondering if I could get a cheap GPS tracking device such as [this one on amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00KNR2YZ4) and reprogram it to send the co-ordinates to my own server? I would then like to generate reports from the DB on my server based on dates etc. I would like to build this for a very small-scale courier company I am planning on starting.

I am an amateur/hobbyist programmer and am looking for a few pointers to help me get on the right track. Pun totally intended.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question. But since no one answered so far, I will just throw in my two cents. First of all, you need to know what GPS signal the (cheap) receiver can track. If it can track only single frequency at L1, there's not much you can do. You have to live with large ionosphere fluctuation error signal.

http://www.navipedia.net/index.php/Ionospheric_Delay

If it can only track code signal (not carrier phase signal) you cannot do code smoothing to reduced the noise level of code signal received.

In other words, if a GPS receiver hardware is limited, there's not much room for improvement.